# How to merge vectors returned from function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function that returns a vector of strings and inside my main function I would like to combine all the vectors returned from the function. However I keep hitting an error `vector iterators incompatible`, but I make sure I return a ptr from the function so the vector is not deleted when the function ends.

```
const unique_ptr<vector<string>> loadTransactions(string filename){
    unique_ptr<vector<string>> transactions = make_unique<vector<T>>();
    //some processing
    return transactions;
}
int main(){
    vector<string> allTransactions;
    for(int i =0; i< 10; ++i){
        unique_ptr<vector<string>> transactions = loadTransactions("filename");
        allTransactions.insert(allTransactions.end(), transactions->begin(), transactions->end());
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: the type of 'allTransactions' is vector<T> and the type of 'transactions' is  vector<T> allTransactions, so you might be facing this issue.

Comment: what is `T` and what is `Transaction`?

Comment: you dont really need a pointer to a vector, you can pass them safely and efficiently around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function can return std::vector without using pointer.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> loadTransactions(string filename) {
    vector<string> transaction {};
    //some processing
    return transaction;
}
int main() {
    vector<string> allTransactions;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        vector<string> transactions = loadTransactions("filename");
        allTransactions.insert(allTransactions.end(), transactions.begin(), transactions.end());
    }

}
```